# Error writing to Windows 10 registry with WindowsAPI/C (strange situation)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-api-code-pack

I am trying to write to my Windows 10 registry, to include a program in Startup.

At the moment I have written the following code, which is not wroking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <winreg.h>
    
int main()
{
    const TCHAR* path = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
    LPDWORD holdResult;
    PHKEY hKey;
    int lResult;
    //lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    lResult = RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "myprogram", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, &holdResult);
    
    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            printf("Key not found.\n");
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            printf("Error opening key.\n");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    printf("Key already existed or not: %p\n", holdResult);
    
    char* szPath = "C:\\Users\\Myname\\Documents\\coolprogram.exe";
    lResult = RegSetValueExA(hKey, "program", 0, REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)szPath, sizeof(wchar_t)*(wcslen(szPath)+1));
    printf("Key successfully set or not: %d\n", lResult);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return 0;
}
```

The strange thing is, although the code does not write anything to the registry, **I get no error message, and the program executes as successful!**

This is what gets printed to the terminal when I run the code:

```
Key already existed or not: 0000000000000002
Key successfully set or not: 0
```

So, the key had already been previously created, and was succesfully set, which **did not** happen, there is nothing in my registry.

I believe this is a permissions problem, because for some reason I cannot alter my registry permissions manually, even after setting myself as owner, it is impossible for me to allow "Full Control" to myself.

But I expected some sort of error, such as "ACCESS DENIED: INSUFFICIENT PERMISSIONS", but I am getting a success. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong key path to `RegCreateKeyEx()`.  You are trying to write your `program` value to `HKCU\myprogram` rather than to `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\...\Run`.

You are also passing invalid pointers to `RegCreateKeyEx()`. Its last 2 parameters expect pointers to `HKEY` and `DWORD` variables, but you are passing in pointers to `HKEY*` and `DWORD*` variables instead.

You are also passing an incorrect parameter to `RegSetValueExA()`, too. You are giving it an ANSI string (OK, since it is an ANSI function), but are passing in a Unicode string length that is 2x the byte size of the actual ANSI string (bad).

In fact, your code shouldn't even compile as shown.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <winreg.h>

int main()
{
    const char* szKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
    const char* szPath = "C:\\Users\\Myname\\Documents\\coolprogram.exe";
    DWORD dwDisposition;
    HKEY hKey;
    LSTATUS lResult;

    //lResult = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, szKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
    lResult = RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, szKey, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &hKey, &dwDisposition);

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error creating key: %ld\n", lResult);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Key already existed or not: %lu\n", dwDisposition);

    lResult = RegSetValueExA(hKey, "program", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, sizeof(TCHAR)*(strlen(szPath)+1));
    printf("Key successfully set or not: %ld\n", lResult);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return 0;
}
```